# Get available dates using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, datepicker

I'm new to Python and web scraping. I have the following calendar as a table and i would like to extract available dates which are in Green background color.

Below is the `HTML` source:

```html
<div id="calendar" class="fc fc-ltr">
    <table class="fc-header" style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="fc-header-left"><span class="fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right" unselectable="on" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="fc-text-arrow">‹</span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="fc-header-center"><span class="fc-header-title"><h2>March 2020</h2></span></td>
                <td class="fc-header-right"><span class="fc-button fc-button-next fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right" unselectable="on" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="fc-text-arrow">›</span></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="fc-content" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid" style="position:relative" unselectable="on">
            <div class="fc-event-container" style="position:absolute;z-index:8;top:0;left:0"></div>
            <table class="fc-border-separate" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="fc-first fc-last">
                        <th class="fc-day-header fc-sun fc-widget-header fc-first" style="width: 50px;">Sun</th>
                        <th class="fc-day-header fc-mon fc-widget-header" style="width: 50px;">Mon</th>
                        <th class="fc-day-header fc-tue fc-widget-header" style="width: 50px;">Tue</th>
                        <th class="fc-day-header fc-wed fc-widget-header" style="width: 50px;">Wed</th>
                        <th class="fc-day-header fc-thu fc-widget-header" style="width: 50px;">Thu</th>
                        <th class="fc-day-header fc-fri fc-widget-header" style="width: 50px;">Fri</th>
                        <th class="fc-day-header fc-sat fc-widget-header fc-last">Sat</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="fc-week fc-first">
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-future fc-first" data-date="2020-03-01">
                            <div style="min-height: 40px;">
                                <div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-02">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-03">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">3</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-04">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">4</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-05">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">5</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-06" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">6</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-03-07" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">7</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="fc-week">
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-future fc-first" data-date="2020-03-08">
                            <div style="min-height: 39px;">
                                <div class="fc-day-number">8</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-09" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">9</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-10">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">10</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-11">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">11</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-12">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">12</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-13" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">13</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-03-14" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">14</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="fc-week">
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-future fc-first" data-date="2020-03-15">
                            <div style="min-height: 39px;">
                                <div class="fc-day-number">15</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-16">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">16</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-17">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">17</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-18">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">18</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-19" style="background-color: rgb(255, 150, 202); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">19</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-20" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">20</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-03-21" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">21</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="fc-week">
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-future fc-first" data-date="2020-03-22" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div style="min-height: 39px;">
                                <div class="fc-day-number">22</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-23" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">23</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-24" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">24</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-25" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">25</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-26" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">26</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-27" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">27</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-03-28" style="color: rgb(255, 106, 106);">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">28</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="fc-week">
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-future fc-first" data-date="2020-03-29" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div style="min-height: 39px;">
                                <div class="fc-day-number">29</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-30" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">30</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2020-03-31" style="background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">31</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-04-01" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-04-02" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-04-03" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">3</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-04-04" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">4</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="fc-week fc-last">
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-first" data-date="2020-04-05" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div style="min-height: 41.3333px;">
                                <div class="fc-day-number">5</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-04-06" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">6</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-04-07" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">7</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-04-08" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">8</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-04-09" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">9</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-04-10" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">10</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-other-month fc-future fc-last" data-date="2020-04-11" style="background-color: white;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="fc-day-number">11</div>
                                <div class="fc-day-content">
                                    <div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="fc-cell-overlay" style="position: absolute; z-index: 3; top: 100.667px; left: 200px; width: 50px; height: 40px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow` community. Kindly edit your question and include the code instead of picture. also please have a look into [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you already hold the `HTML` source under `selenium` `driver.page_source` so we are going to pass it to the `soup` and `parse` it.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("td", {'style': 'background-color: rgb(188, 237, 145); cursor: pointer;'}):
    print(item.get("data-date"))
```

Output:

```
2020-03-09
2020-03-22
2020-03-23
2020-03-24
2020-03-25
2020-03-26
2020-03-29
2020-03-30
2020-03-31
```

In case if you don't have `bs4` installed, you can install it via `pip install bs4 --user`